# Trying to write blue screen of death message in github through typescript

Tags: typescript, windows, github, operating-system, bsod

Display a BSOD message (on the CLI) when the kernel traps an OS error.

Here is the code for a kernel trapping an error:

```
public krnTrapError(msg) {
    Control.hostLog("OS ERROR - TRAP: " + msg);
    // TODO: Display error on console, perhaps in some sort of
    // colored screen. (Maybe blue?)
    _StdOut.putText("Error found".toString());
    this.krnShutdown();
}
```

I do not know how to make a screen blue or attach a message.